# else statement is ignored in react

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, popup, response

when i am trying to perform this task to change password, everything works fine if the response is 200 and it also gives me the pop up window, but if its not it dosent perform the else statement,it like no else. completely ignored.

here is the code

```
const submitForm = () => {

    let form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('old_password', formValues.oldpass);
    form_data.append('new_password', formValues.newpass);
    try {
        axios.put(baseUrl + '/change-password/', form_data,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Token ${token}`
                }
            }


        ).then((response) => {
            const Swal = require('sweetalert2');
            console.log(response.data);
            if (response.status === 200) {

                Swal.fire(
                    'Great!',
                    'Password updated successfully',
                    'success'
                )
            }
            else {
                alert('error ', 'password has not been changed !!');
            }

        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);

    }
};
```

please help i am new to react and i`ve had this issue for days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axios throws the response if the status code is something else than 2xx. Which means that if you get e.g. 4xx or 5xx the `then` clause is not run. Instead you need a `catch` clause that will handle this case.

```
.then((response) => {
    const Swal = require('sweetalert2');
    console.log(response.data);
    Swal.fire('Great!', 'Password updated successfully', 'success')
}).catch((response) => {
    alert('error ', 'password has not been changed !!');
    console.log(error);
});
```

In this case you can remove `try`-`catch` as it won't catch any errors.

Optionally you can `await` the result of the axios call to have the current `catch` clause catch the error. Then you'll also need the function to be `async`.

```
const submitForm = async () => {
    let form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('old_password', formValues.oldpass);
    form_data.append('new_password', formValues.newpass);
    try {
        await axios.put(baseUrl + '/change-password/', form_data,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Token ${token}`
                }
            }
        ).then((response) => {
            const Swal = require('sweetalert2');
            console.log(response.data);
            Swal.fire('Great!', 'Password updated successfully', 'success')
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        alert('error ', 'password has not been changed !!');
    }
};
```

https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors

Comment: @AMAL i edited my answer to explain better and remove a mistake

Comment: thanks. it works fine now. you really saved my life

Comment: @AMAL no worries. please accept my answer if it solved your problem